# Using Telegram to send personalized messages to any phone number

Tags: api, bots, telegram

I am looking at the Telegram API (Standard and BOT) to communicate to parents at a school. I had a look at both APIs. Is it true that one can only send to people in your Telegram associated contact list? With the BOT, will it be possible for users to register to the BOT and then I have their IDs to send messages to? I am working with a phone number as this is part of the database I have. I am a bit confused. Each message will be different so it is not a broadcast to all users but personalized with important information per parent. Perhaps Telegram is not the platform for this?

Thanks!

Jaco

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Telegram platform is suitable for your task.

You can invite users to your bot by having only phone numbers (e.g. sharing link using SMS) and then if the user subscribed - you'll be able to send personalized (aka. transactional) messages.

To identify a user who subscribed to bot you can send a special message to ask phone number.

Or you can use libraries for [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) (e.g. `pyTelegramBotAPI`), which can allow sending direct Telegram messages (not bot) programmatically.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way (to make it easier as we work with people that sometimes are not so tech experienced) that one could import a database of phone numbers into a Telegram account programmatically and then send messages as if I am using an SMS service. I am just trying to make it as easy as possible. Some people are reluctant to use technology.

Comment: @Systellence yes, there are many libraries for [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) (e.g. `pyTelegramBotAPI`), which can allow sending direct Telegram messages (not bot) programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. That I understand, BUT it seems that if you only have a phone number you will not be able to send a message? (This now with only using the API and NOT the BOT API) - standard API. If the case, I will not be able to use it. I hoped that I could import phone numbers by some means and then send according to phone number and not ID. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Systellence if you have all these phone numbers saved in your phone contact book - you should be able to send message to them.

Comment: Thanks. But that is the problem. We have a database of phone numbers but they are in a system and not in telegram. Can one import them programatically into Telegram? By using code? So if they are imported like that then yes we could send a message I guess

Comment: @Systellence yes, you can do that programmatically, look for [inputPhoneContact](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputPhoneContact) method in Telegram API documentation and library which you'll use.